# The Domain and range of functions

Tags: functions, inverse-function, function-and-relation-composition

Do the domain and range have to be in accordance with each other? Meaning that for this question

[image]

the range is $f^{-1}(x) > 4$ and so is the domain $\frac{13}{8} < x < 3$, or $x < 3$?

The range is only true for the domain values between $\frac{13}{8} < x < 3$, but the mark scheme says the domain is $x < 3$,

Comment: You might want to explain how you arrived at the values for the domain

Comment: the range is only true for those values, if you make the go lower then 13/8, the range is not > 4 anymore. i got 13/8 by making the inverse function equal to 4